# Issue with net tiers not generating custom stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, codesmith, .nettiers

I am using Net Tiers and codesmiths to generate my data layer.
For some strange reason, it is no longer generating my custom stored procedures.

When I view the report at the end of the generation, it is not listing any procs, get the all exist in the database?

Is there an option that should be checked to allow these procedures to be generated?

Any one got any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend posting this on the [.netTiers forums](http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16.aspx) so the .netTiers team can respond to this. I'd also include your version information of the templates and CodeSmith that you are using. Has anything changed in this database or on the machine you are generating from?

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski